# Where does my upper tube from my 2008 cbr600rr coolant reservoir tank go to?

Tags: honda

I just recently bought an 08 cbr600rr and on the coolant reservoir there is two tubes attached. One goes to the radiator and the other one goes into something sort of under the gas tank. Just curious if anyone knows what that is because I busted that tube and need to replace it. Thanks!

Comment: Pictures wiuld help... “something sort of under the gas tank” could be the fuel tap or carb...

Comment: @SolarMike - on the '08 CBR, the fuel lines are pressure lines which feed the injectors. The only other lines are drain lines, or vacuum relief/breather lines for the tank. So no carbs and generic looking fuel lines like all the older bikes have.

Comment: @the_storyteller so pictures would help then...

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 0):

On my '08 CBR1000RR, they are two separate systems. One tube drains the spill catcher/breather on the gas tank, and another tube drains from the coolant reservoir in case it's overfull and needs a place to expand. Both tubes just drain to under the bike.

If you are having difficulty determining what a part is, you might use [this diagram](https://www.bikebandit.com/oem-parts/2008-honda-cbr600rr/o/m17500#sch558696), which details the function of each part.

Comment: that makes sense for it to be two different drainage hoses then because the one coming from the coolant reservoir is thinner than the one coming from under the gas tank. I though it was like a progressive hose or something. I think that answers my question then! Thank you! So what is the spill catch and breather? This is my first bike and I have a lot of learning still to do

Comment: The breather line allows the tank to breath, so it doesn't get pressurized or draw vacuum when heating or cooling. There's also an inset ring around the gas cap which helps catch spills, although I'm not sure that is the intended purpose.